# Keras model.fit() returns TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable when using tf.data.Dataset.from_generator

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to use tensorflow data api to replace my current data loading pipeline.

**X_train** shape: 385880x105624 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64>'

**y_train** shape: 385880x405415 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32>'

**X_test** shape: 96470x105624 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64>'

**y_test** shape: 96470x405415 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32>'

Previous data loading code:

```
def extract_array(M, a):
    return M[a].toarray()


def get_generator(X, y, size):
    i = 0
    a = list(range(X.shape[0]))
    masksize = len(a)
    np.random.shuffle(a)
    while 1:
        if i + size > masksize:
            np.random.shuffle(a)
            i = 0
        j = i + size
        xx = extract_array(X, a[i:j])
        yy = extract_array(y, a[i:j])
        i = j
        yield xx, yy

bs = 128
Gt = get_generator(Xt, yt, bs)
Gv = get_generator(Xv, yv, bs)



optimizer = Adam(lr=0.001)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

mc = ModelCheckpoint(model_path + f'/w-exp{exp_num}09d_{weigths_name}_{dateTimeObj}.hdf5', verbose=1,save_best_only=True)

rlr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=2, verbose=1, epsilon=0.0001)

es = EarlyStopping(patience=5, verbose=1)


model.fit(Gt,epochs=epochs, verbose=1, callbacks=[mc, es, rlr], validation_data=Gv)
```

I have changed the generator to use the tf.data api,

```
Gt = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: get_generator(Xt, yt, bs), output_types=(np.float32, np.int32), )

Gv = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: get_generator(Xv, yv, bs), output_types=(np.float32, np.int32), )
```

While I try to call the `model.fit(Gt, validation_data=Gv, epochs=1,)` the program throws

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-162-f55f4b3c2f66> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(Gt, validation_data=Gv, epochs=1,)

~/anaconda3/envs/rollout-learn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

~/anaconda3/envs/rollout-learn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~/anaconda3/envs/rollout-learn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    853       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    854       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 855       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    856     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    857       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

```
for count_batch in Gt.repeat().batch(1).take(1):
  print(count_batch)

(<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1, 1, 128, 105624), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[[0.27083334, 0.2       , 0.0952381 , ..., 0.        ,
           0.        , 0.        ],
          [0.04166667, 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
           0.        , 0.        ],
          [0.08333334, 0.        , 0.04761905, ..., 0.        ,
           0.        , 0.        ],
          ...,
          [0.33333334, 0.2       , 0.14285715, ..., 0.        ,
           0.        , 0.        ],
          [0.14583333, 0.        , 0.04761905, ..., 0.        ,
           0.        , 0.        ],
          [0.1875    , 0.4       , 0.14285715, ..., 0.        ,
           0.        , 0.        ]]]]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1, 1, 128, 405415), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[[[[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
          ...,
          [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]]]]], dtype=int32)>)
```

What am I missing here? Any clue would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you remove `lambda` in `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`?

Comment: Got this working after a kernel restart in Jupyter notebook.